# Make Python Compare Lists

Tags: python, list

Very new to python so I have no idea how to any of this.

Basically I have a list like this:

```
notes = [60, 62, 64, 60, 67, 69, 71]
```

I want python to compare that list to 12 other lists that have similar numbers, and find out which of these 12 lists shares the most values with the original list.
How can I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already try anything? Maybe you could share something you tried and how you would start going about this task. For example you could do that in a for loop for each list that you compare and iterate over the elements and count the number of elements that the lists share with the original one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how does the program receive the other lists but this is an example of how could you do this:

```
notes = [60, 62, 64, 60, 67, 69, 71]

other_notes = [
    [60, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [60, 62, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [60, 62, 64, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [60, 62, 64, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [60, 62, 64, 60, 3, 4, 5],
    [60, 62, 64, 60, 67, 5],
    [60, 62, 64, 60, 67, 71],
    [60, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [60, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [60, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [60, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [60, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
]

max_value = (-1, -1)

for i in range(len(other_notes)):
    data = set(notes) & set(other_notes[i])
    if len(data) > max_value[0]:
        max_value = (len(data), i)

print("The list that shares more values with the original is {0}. The index position is {1}".
      format(other_notes[max_value[1]], max_value[0]))
```